# What are the Microsoft SharePoint Authentication modes supported in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sharepoint

I am developing a application that can communicate with anyone's Microsoft SharePoint sites. I am new to this approach. I have noticed that there are both SOAP and REST APIs are available to get details of contents from the site. When I am trying to Authenticate the site programmatically, it gives "PasswordNotMatching" and I am not able to authenticate.

How can we do the authentication with SharePoint from iOS effectively? Also, I came know that there are different authentication modes in SharePoint, Forms, Windows and Office 365. Which is the mode supported from iOS?